# Need help getting CSS grid to work on a Tumblr theme

Tags: html, css, grid, tumblr

As the title states, I am trying to get help with a CSS grid code on a Tumblr theme. So far everything works great, with just two issues: there is a grey background that shouldn't be there in the first place on the posts, and all grid posts are the same length when they should be different sizes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfjyp.jpg Here is an image with the code so far and a preview of how it looks. Most of the grid code is in ".content".  Any help received for this issue is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Someone mentioned I should paste the code as a block, so here you go!

```
.content {
    position:flex;
    {block:IfGridLayout}
    top:0px;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:1fr 2fr;
    break-inside: avoid;
    max-width:800px;
    {block:IndexPage}
    left:270px;
    width:990px;
    {block:IndexPage}

    {block:PermalinkPage}
    top:0px;
    float:right;
    width:540px!important;
    {/block:PermalinkPage}

    {block:IfGridLayout}
}

.posts {
    position:flex;
    {block:IndexPage}
    {block:IfGridLayout};
    {/block:IfGridLayout}

    {block:IfNotGridLayout}
    width:540px!important;
    {/block:IfNotGridLayout}
    height:auto;
    {/block:IndexPage}

    {block:PermalinkPage}float:right;width:540px!important;{/block:PermalinkPage}
    margin:0px 0px 50px 40px;
    padding:30px;
    background:{color:Content Border Background};
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include your code in a code block, not as an image. See stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you add the HTML also? Additionally add the link to your blog, that will make it much easier to help you.